# Detect what computer/server I'm using in VB

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio

I am writing an application that uses a database, through SQL Server. I'm also using two computers to do it. I want to put in an if statement to execute code for the appropriate computer since my database connection string will be unique to each machine. Each computer will use an identical, but not synchronized database. I just don't want to jump back and forth to change connection strings all the time.

```
If Computer01 then 
   use connection-string01
else 
   use connection-string02
end if
```

Comment: Why not manage the `<connectionStrings>` per-machine (at the config level)? There's no need for "computer02" to have a connection string it can't use. Likewise, if you were to ever have a "computer03", do you really want to be pushing new bits?

Comment: See `Environment.MachineName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will return the name of the computer in VB.NET

```
Dim ComputerName As String
ComputerName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
If ComputerName = Computer01 Then
    'Connection String 1
Else
    'Connection String 2
End If
```

Comment: While this does correctly answer the question asked, I would just like to note that this is not the correct solution for the real problem. You don't want to check for explicit machine names in code, you want to read the connection string from either an app config file or an environment variable.

Comment: Hi Cris, thanks!  Yes, you are correct, as the original question did not include a definition for Computer01 and Computer02 I made the assumption that values were being assigned to the variables dynamically.  Cheers!